# Ubuntu wifi slowdown if Windows 10 PC is working simultaneously

Tags: networking, windows-10

I'm using my Ubuntu 16.04 for a long time and haven't had any troubles with my wifi. Recently my neighbour bought Windows 10 machine. I noticed that while he's connected to our wifi, wifi on my PC slows down dramatically. For example, if I ping our router I get this results:

[image: ping with Win 10 working]

While if it's not connected to our wifi I get this results:

[image]

Does anyone has any ideas what's going on here?